# How to change the Delphi debugger's "Notify on Language Exceptions flag" from an IDE Expert

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am writing a Delphi IDE expert. Is it possible to change the debugger's "Notify on Language Exceptions flag" from the expert? How?

Comment: Maybe you can hook yourself to the IDE and see what happens (which functions are called) when you press the OK button in the "Options"? It is probably a lot of work but I don't know other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

These settings are maintained in the registry.  The precise path will vary according to Delphi version but for XE2 they are to be found here:

```
HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\Debugging\Embarcadero Debuggers\Language Exception Classes
```

Name of each value in this key is the exception class to which the value relates and the value is a string with the value "1" to ignore the exception class or "0" to not ignore (same as removing the value entirely).

However, changes made directly in the registry to these settings are not picked up by the IDE unless you restart the IDE which is probably not what you wish for in your expert.

Unfortunately I am not aware of a mechanism for changing these settings in a way that the IDE will be aware of dynamically, or for causing the IDE to reload these settings without restarting (which isn't to say that such a mechanism doesn't exist, only that I am not aware of any).

Comment: Good to know but does not help me. I would need to change the flag while the IDE is running.